# Correct using VLCj

Tags: java, libvlc, vlcj

I try to use VLCj to get access to web-cameras. I am using this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create player.
    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    DirectMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newDirectMediaPlayer(
            320, 240, 
            new RenderCallback() {
                @Override
                public void display(Memory arg0) {
                    // Do nothing.
                }
         });

    // Options setup.
    String[] options = new String[]{};
    String mrl = "v4l2:///dev/video0"; // Linux

    // Start preocessing.
    mediaPlayer.startMedia(mrl, options);

    BufferedImage bufImg;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        bufImg = mediaPlayer.getSnapshot();

        // Do something with BufferedImage...
        // ...
    }

    // Stop precessing.
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer = null;

    System.out.println("Finish!");
}
```

And this code **partially works** -- I can get and work with `BufferedImage`, but:

- I got an **error in to output**: `[0x7f0a4c001268] main vout display error: Failed to set on top`
- When main loop is finished and camera was disabled **program don't finished**! I see `Finish!` message, but program not return control into IDE or console.

**UPD:**
I am using openSUSE 12.2 x64, VLC 2.0.3 installed and working properly for all video files, library VLCj 2.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re your native window: VLCj opens a shared instance to the VLC library.

**A headless media palyer is NOT intended to have a video or audio output!**

In fact, if you need anything to play (and not to stream to anywhere else) you need to create either an *output window* or use a *direct media player* (may be much more complicated)
So, if a headless player needs to play something it opens a native window to perform the playback!

Source: http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/wiki/index.php?title=Vlcj_Media_Players

Re the error: the **video display component MUST be the top component** of the panel, window or whereever it is added to. Otherwise it will throw the error

> main vout display error: Failed to set on top

Furthermore, if you put anything over the component it will **destroy the video output** which won't work anymore!

Anyway, I don't know how the DirectMediaPlayer works in detail but VLCj has some weird behaviour... Maybe `getSnapshot()` needs a video display component but I'm not sure.

Re your not finishing program: you join to finish your own thread. This **can't work** because your thread "sleeps" until the other thread who is waited for has been terminated but as this is your own thread it "sleeps" and won't terminate.
You can test this behaviour with this short code in a main method:

```
System.out.println("Test start");
Thread.currentThread().join();
System.out.println("Test stop");
```

You will **NEVER** reach the "Test stop" statement.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel M.! Now native window is not showing, but in output I see another error and main program still not finished! Have you any ideas why it happends?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot and updated my answer re the error. If the video surface or video display component is NOT the top component of the panel, ... it will drop this error -> NEVER lie anything on top of the video display component because this will kill the output.

Comment: I have no clue why it is not stopping but I hope I could clarify some other things. However, VLCj officially ONLY supports Ubuntu 64-bit version and Windows - that's why I asked.

Comment: (You could try commenting out the getSnapshot() in the loop and see if the vout error gets thrown again.)

Comment: I comment `getSnapshot()` but vout display error still happens.

Comment: I am not using display component in current test -- just write BufferedImage into files or just drop, but still get `main vout display error: Failed to set on top` and can not finished main program.

Comment: Weird. I don't really have any other idea. Usually, this error gets thrown if VLCj can't move its video display component to the top but I'm not familiar with the DirectMediaPlayer as I have used it only once for some tests.
btw.. I updated my answer with the cause why your program is not finishing.

Comment: Thank you, for your response! 
I update code (remove `Thread.currentThread().join();` an can see `Finish!` message) into the topic, but program still not finished.

Comment: You mean the program does not finish although you reach the last line of code. Afaik you need to release all VLCj parts: mediaPlayer.release() AND mediaPlayerFactory.release(). This will force VLCj to release all resources and shut down itself.

Comment: Also one comment -- I should use `HeadlessMediaPlayer` but set parameters into player factory according to [this example](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/thumbs/ThumbsTest.java).

Answer (score 3):

This code working properly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Configure player factory.
    String[] VLC_ARGS = {
            "--intf", "dummy",          // no interface
            "--vout", "dummy",          // we don't want video (output)
            "--no-audio",               // we don't want audio (decoding)
            "--no-video-title-show",    // nor the filename displayed
            "--no-stats",               // no stats
            "--no-sub-autodetect-file", // we don't want subtitles
            "--no-inhibit",             // we don't want interfaces
            "--no-disable-screensaver", // we don't want interfaces
            "--no-snapshot-preview",    // no blending in dummy vout
    };
    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(VLC_ARGS);

    // Create player.
    HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();

    // Select input device.
    String mrl = "v4l2:///dev/video0";  // Linux

    // Start processing.
    mediaPlayer.startMedia(mrl);

    BufferedImage bufImg;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        bufImg = mediaPlayer.getSnapshot();

        // Do something with BufferedImage...
        // ...
    }

    // Stop processing.
    mediaPlayer.stop();

    // Finish program.
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayerFactory.release();
}
```